# Excel merge cells equivalent in SQL

Tags: excel, postgresql

I am trying to generate SQL output similar to how Excel does the merge cells.

Sample output from SQL select statement

| Name | Country | State | years | lived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | USA | CA | 2 | 2 |
| Alice | USA | NYC | 1 | 1 |
| Alice | USA | MI | 5 | 5 |
| Bob | USA | CA | 1 | 1 |
| Bob | USA | NYC | 8 | 8 |
| Bob | USA | IL | 4 | 4 |

I am trying to convert the output in below format using SQL query, so I can directly export to Excel, instead of modifying in excel separately.

| Name | Country | State | years | lived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | CA | 2 |  |
|  |  | NYC | 1 |  |
| Alice | USA | MI | 5 | 8 |
|  |  | CA | 1 |  |
|  |  | NYC | 8 |  |
| Bob | USA | IL | 4 | 13 |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want `SQL` statement or excel solution?

Comment: @Harun24HR: I am trying get a sql statement, so i can directly insert into the excel with desired format

Comment: I think it is not possible by `SQL` to get exact output. You may need to design a report then export that report to excel file.

Comment: @Harun24HR: How do i do that exactly? Sorry i may be asking basic questions